# How does tornado.cash work?

Tags: tornado-cash

I came to this site: https://tornado.cash/

And I'm trying to figure out how it works. Looks like the user has to deposit and withdrawal "in full", and this make it easy to associate the IN and OUT transactions by comparing the amount of tokens or ETH in the transaction.

Am I wrong about it?

Answer (score 0):

I am not too familiar with tornado.cash, but you cannot associate those transactions as easily as you stated it simply because they are only some fixed amount of ETH you can deposit (0.1, 1, 10, 100) and not a custom amount.